# What is it that performs the cast in C code, compiled with gcc on Linux?

Tags: c, gcc, casting

**Short question:** if I do this:

```
double x = 3.152;
int y = (int) x;
```

`y` should store the value `3`.  Does `gcc` call a function that performs that cast?  If so, where is it located, and how can I write my own and point `gcc` to use it?

**Long question with background information:**

I'm writing an **OS**, and am re-writing the `C` standard library, as a personal learning project.  As a result, I've disabled a lot of things in my compilation of C code.  Specifically, I use the flags:

> -nostartfiles -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -nodefaultlibs

I've been having great luck working with ints, but I am now moving on to working with doubles, and have tried to cast a double to an int.  What ends up happening is a whole lot of nothing.  So I suspect that somewhere in all of those things I've disabled is the code that actually performs the cast.  I'm happy to re-write it, since this is fascinating learning for me, but I don't know *what* I'm supposed to re-write.

Comment: I think the first thing you have to do is get the Dragon Book. Second step is to write your own compiler for C.

Comment: Possibly, but I think the easier thing would be to look into how gcc does it, and move my own functions to replace gcc's, no?

Comment: Yes, but I believe that is not possible. There isn't a function to replace. Casting is an internal compiler mechanism.

Comment: Compile it with gcc using `-S` argument and look into the assembly code generated.

Comment: @avysk This is exactly what I did (out of curiosity) finding an assembler command `fistpl` and (after googling a little bit) identified it as conversion from floating point to `int`. One of the commands before must be responsible for loading the floating point value to the FPU...

Comment: @Scheff: Which architecture? It certainly is not identicall for all.

Comment: There is enough informatrion to read how to use gcc with a freestanding environment. One of them is you must always explicitly link `libgcc`. Not sure why you disabled builtins; they provide a lot of helpful stuff especially for bare-metal programming. Oh, and just that: using floats on an OS is a really bad idea. There is a reason the Linux kernel does not allow them. You should reconsider your design/architecture.

Comment: @Olaf Intel (I7). As far as I saw, MS asm and gcc asm have different syntax. But at least, the mnemonics seem to be the same.

Comment: @Scheff: I don't see evidence in the question this is about i7 or even x86 in general. It is not about the assembly syntax, but the whole instruction set/architecture!

Comment: Oh, my bad, it is in fact on an x86.  Also, I looked at the generated assembly and the cast instruction is there (cvttssd2si).  So I guess I asked the wrong question.  If my casting is happening...why don't I see it?  I guess that could be my string library acting up...

Comment: Update: It turns out that the cast is happening, but for some reason it is casting to 0 no matter what.  However, the cast instruction is there, so presumably it should be going through correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I compiled your code with the -S option to give assembler and had a look at it. Admittedly I am using Clang on OS X but i think gcc will do the same thing. What it did was use a [cvttsd2si](https://www.tptp.cc/mirrors/siyobik.info/instruction/CVTTSD2SI.html) instruction which converts a double precision float to a signed integer in one machine language instruction.

That's specific to the x86_64 architecture. If there is no equivalent instruction in the target architecture, the compiler will insert a call to a built in function that does the conversion.

If your program compiles and links (without any libraries or built ins) without any problems, then your code is probably using a single instruction, otherwise I would expect a link error, but you do need to make sure that the compiler is not optimising your code so that it does not need to do the conversion. For example

```
 int main()
 {
     double y = 3.14159;
     int x = (int) y;
     return 0;
 }
```

could easily get optimised to just do the `return 0` bit.

Comment: That's why, I returned `x` instead. Thus, I could see the result with `echo $?`. Then I applied the command line options of the OP. Applying all of them caused a link error, but applying only some of them it mostly links. Thus, I ran the distinct binaries and got mostly 3, but once 127 and once 0. Very funny...

Comment: `undefined reference to '__main'`. I forgot to mention that I ran this on cygwin. So, I need something like `cygwin1.dll` which is probably part of the default libraries.

Comment: @Scheff That's probably the prolog routine that sets up the stack and arguments and calls main. I wrote a bare bones operating system for Raspberry Pi a few years ago and I had the same problem. I had to link the program with an assembly routine to replace the default prolog code.

Comment: @Scheff I also had an undefined reference to `_int32divs`. It turns out that 32 bit ARM has no hardware support for integer division.

Comment: This reminds me about 6**5**10 CPU (Commodore C64): 8 bit data, 16 bit address, no integer multiplication, not to mention integer division. This was very good to learn bit fiddling...

Comment: @Scheff 6**5**10 actually. I cut my teeth on the Commodore PET in Basic and 6502 assembler. I still find it quite therapeutic (I had to write a lot of 6502 for test cases for my PET emulation).

Comment: @Scheff Also, as a 6502 programmer, you are qualified to maintain [Arnold Schwarzenegger](http://www.pagetable.com/?p=64)

Answer (score 2):

It is part of the language just like adding two numbers, the compiler has to know how to do that and then apply that to the target (in order to fully support that language).  It may or may not call a function depending on what the target supports, if there is no floating point hardware in the target, then sure it has to call a soft library to do the double to int conversion.  There are sometimes reasons why hard float cant do certain things and/or compiler implementation and design reasons they may still choose to call a function to perform the double to int even if there is a hard FPU.

These libraries if they are used are sometimes called compiler libraries, in gcc in the category of gcclib or gcc libraries.  Generally not something you see (buried behind the scenes)...It is not limited to floating point, you will see similar library calls for addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, as well as float for operations that the C language supports that the target doesnt necessarily directly support.  (adding two 64 bit integers on a 32 bit processor, integer division on a processor with no hardware division, signed multiplication on a processor that only supports unsigned multiplication, etc).

There is no one answer to this question, it varies by compiler, compiler version and target.

EDIT

As far as writing an operating system goes this is buried in the compiler you should not be exposed to it at the operating system level.  The compiler has to do its job of producing working code for the target (which your os is part of the target, but...) which at the end of the day is a lot of machine code, some of which is direct machine code that performs the double to int or a gcc library that is linked in that has machine code that performs this operation.  So your operating system should not care.  Now saying that there are times where the soft implementation of something has for example a divide by zero and wants to take some action on that which might be a C library call which might then become a system call.  A hardware implementation direct division float or int, might have an interrupt which the operating system might have to support in this situation.  So there is a possible connection there.   IEEE-754 float does have, or at least the last time I read it a while ago, has software/operating system hooks, here again divide by zero that is trapped vs a divide by zero that isnt may have different results.  for the case of a float to int operation, there is the situation of a NaN being converted to int and dont know the spec answer on that for trapped vs no trapped, but if your compiler is generating soft float functions for that it may drag in some other calls that it assumes are being supported by other gcc libraries and or C standard libraries, which then might connect to something in your operating system.

Comment: On 32 bit x86 implementations that support hardware floating point, there is a trap that happens the first time you access a floating point register after a context switch. This is so that a context switch doesn't have to load the floating point registers of the new process if it doesn't use floating point. That's probably why floating point is banned in the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not (have to) call a function. It simply "knows" (by virtue of being a compiler for a particular target processor) which instruction(s) to emit in order to do the conversion.

It *could* of course choose to implement this as a call to some subroutine, if it's a lot of work, but on typical x86 processors it's a single instruction so it just emits that.

You should inspect the code you got, the most likely cause (for code like the one in the question, with a simple constant expression being cast) is that no conversion was performed at runtime at all.

Comment: Didn't I quite clearly say that, in the middle paragraph? I tried to covert most bases. :)

Comment: I don't see the question specifies x86 as target. And not sure what you mean with "typical x86". What would be an "untypical x86"? If you mean: "the mostly used architecture x86": that is actually a minor architecture for C code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will call a function or probably inlined code.

The requirement to convert a floating point type to an integer is so common that there is probably a special machine language instruction for it. You can't access that from C. What you can do is look at the bit pattern of the floating point number, extract the exponent, sign and mantissa, then do the conversion by shifting the mantissa by the correct amount, you also have to add a leading 1.

On machines which don't have a dedicated FPU that's how the cast works.